# Perform nested search using elasticsearch dsl

Tags: python, json, linux, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

Hi I want to perform a nested search using elasticsearch dsl where a document field has nested json data in it so I want specific nested key values from it like -

Below is the document:-

```
{
  "_index" : "data",
  "_type" : "users",
  "_id" : "15",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "data" : {
      "Gender" : "M",
      "Marks" : "80",
      "name" : "Mayank",
      "Address" : "India"
    },
    "last_updated" : "2017-04-09T01:54:33.764573"
  }
}
```

I only want field values which are stored in an array.

fields_want = ['name', 'Marks']

Output should be like -> {"name":"Mayank", "Marks":"80"}

Elasticsearch dsl documentation is pretty hard to understandand for me.
https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#

Dsl code:-

```
client = Elasticsearch()
s = Search(using=client, index="data") \
    .query("match", _type="users") \
    .query("match", _id=15)
response = s.execute()
for hit in s:
    print(hit.data)
```

From this code I can get the whole json object under data field.

Can somebody guide me here ?

Comment: what do you mean by "{"name":"Mayank", "Marks":"80"}". You cannot tell elastic rest api to model the response according to you. This violates REST api design. To filter the fields you can use "stored_fields". but the structure of the response is at elastic discretion and follows REST api design. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-stored-fields.html

Comment: I don't want to structure the response but you can see the nested fields in "data" key.  `"_source":  { "data" :{...}, "last_updated":"<date>"}`. I want to get specific field only from "data" key ex. "name" key value or "Marks" key value my code return whole "data" key value i.e. all fields in "data" key.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved. 
I have used source filter to get nested output.

```
client = Elasticsearch()
s = Search(using=client, index="data") \
    .query("match", _type="users") \
    .query("match", _id=15) \
    .source(['data.Name', 'data.Marks'])
response = s.execute()
print response
```

Output -

```
{u'Name': u'Mayank', u'Marks': u'80'}
```